# Thymeleaf; "an error happened during template parsing"

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I´m currently having trouble with springboot and the error "An error happened during template parsing(template: "class path resource [templates/mainpage.html])".

I´ve tried to reinstall different version of lombok because I though this might be the problem but nothing so far seemed to work. I´m using gradle with Eclipse as IDE.
Any help is appreciated, found a few threads with the same problem due to different springBootVersions, but tried old and new ones and it didn´t fixed it for me either.

My **build.gradle** looks like this:

```
buildscript {
ext {
    springBootVersion = '2.0.3.RELEASE'
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
}
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

group = 'test'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
 mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
  compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf')
  compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
  runtime('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools')
  testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
  compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.2'
}
```

My **Controller**:

```
package test;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;

@Controller
public class ExampleController {

    @GetMapping(path = "/")
    public String mainpage(Model model) {
        return "mainpage";
    }

    @PostMapping(path = "/")
    public String calculate(Model model, Calc cal) {
        model.addAttribute("cal", cal);
        return "mainpage";
    }
}
```

The **Calc.java** file with lombok:

```
@Data
public class Calc {

    private Long val1;
    private Long val2;

    public Long getSum() {
        return this.val1 + this.val2;
    }
}
```

And my **mainpage.html**:

```html
<html>
    <title>Homepage</title> 
    <body>
        <form method="post">
            <input type="text" name="val1" th:value="${cal.val1}"> </input>
            <input type="text" name="val2" th:value="${cal.val2}"> </input>
            <input type="submit"></input> 
        </form> 
        <p th:text="| ${cal.val1} and ${cal.val2} equals ${cal.sum}|"></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: "2018-10-13 13:19:12.590 ERROR 9592 --- [nio-8000-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/mainpage.html]")] with root cause

org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1007E: Property or field 'val1' cannot be found on null"

Comment: @buræquete I think this is the message you are looking for, caused by val1 seemingly not being initalised maybe because Calc is not being recognized properly which could then again come back to being a problem with lombok but I installed it a few times directly into the source and via eclipse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem arises from your first endpoint, where you have not defined a `Calc` type attribute, therefore the parsing of `mainpage.html` fails due to lack of this attribute, and failing to map its class type (fields) into the referred ones in the html.

You should either use `?` operator from Thymeleaf (which is the correct way of handling this);

```
<input type="text" name="val1" th:value="${cal?.val1}"> </input>
```

or just pass an empty `Calc` object as attribute in your first endpoint;

```
@GetMapping(path="/")
public String mainpage(Model model) {

    model.addAttribute("cal", new Calc());
    return "mainpage";
}
```

`"?"` operator (safe navigation operator) is to cover null cases, for example `cal?.val1` means, use `val1` field value of `cal` attribute, if `cal` is non-null, else use empty.

Answer (score 2):

Downgrade `springBootVersion` to '1.5.10.RELEASE' and add the following class to your application package.

```
@Configuration
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    @Description("Thymeleaf template resolver serving HTML 5")
    public ClassLoaderTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
        ClassLoaderTemplateResolver templateResolver = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setPrefix("templates/");
        templateResolver.setCacheable(false);
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        templateResolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
        templateResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        return templateResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletContextTemplateResolver servletContextTemplateResolverResolver() {
        final ServletContextTemplateResolver resolver =
                new ServletContextTemplateResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/templates/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".html");
        resolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
        resolver.setCacheable(false);
        resolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        return resolver;
    }

    @Bean
    @Description("Thymeleaf template engine with Spring integration")
    public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
        SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.addTemplateResolver(new UrlTemplateResolver());
        templateEngine.addDialect(new SpringSecurityDialect());
        templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
        return templateEngine;
    }


    @Bean
    @Description("Thymeleaf view resolver")
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
        viewResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        return viewResolver;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow - downgrading to 1.5.10.RELEASE breaks my entire app.  Is there another alternative?